# How to find all possible combinations of balls?

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, counting

I need to find all possible ways to combine `k` amount of balls from `n` types of balls.

Let's say if there are 3 types of balls and I want to take 2, result I want is:

```
     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     2
     2     3
     3     3
```

I am trying to do it with the following line:

```
unique(nchoosek(repmat(1:n, 1, n), k), 'rows')
```

I get:

```
     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     3     1
     3     2
     3     3
```

How to do find all combinations with repetitions but without duplicates of same numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *n* types of balls, taking *k*, you have *n<sup>k</sup>* combinations, in MATLAB computed as `count = n^k`.

You can list these combinations using [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```matlab
n = 3;
k = 2;
l = repmat({1:n},k,1);                         % k repetitions of the n balls
[l{:}] = ndgrid(l{:});                         % find all combinations
l = cellfun(@(e)e(:),l,'uniformoutput',false); % make each l{i} a vector
l = [l{:}];                                    % turn into a single vector
```

Now you can verify that `size(l,1) == n^k`.

The advantage of this code over the one in the OP using `nchoosek` with `repmat` is that no repeated combinations will be generated, so this code should work with larger values of `k` and `n` than the code in the OP.

---

The edit to the question suggests that permutations of the same subset should not be counted separately. You can filter the list `l` as follows to remove permutations of the same set of balls:

```matlab
l = unique(sort(l,2),'rows');
```